# Get the rows that are not shared between two data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames with the exact same column, but one of them have 1000 rows (`df1`), and one of them 500 (`df2`). The rows of `df2` are also found in the data frame `df1`, but I want the rows that are not.

For example, lets say this is `df1`:

```
          Gender       Age
1           F           43
3           F           56
33          M           76
476         F           30
810         M           29
```

and `df2`:

```
          Gender       Age
3           F           56
476         F           30
```

I want a new data frame, `df3`, that have the unshared rows:

```
          Gender       Age
1           F           43
33          M           76
810         M           29
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pd.Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
df3 = df1.loc[df1.index.difference(df2.index)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This has many ways.
I know 3 ways for it.

**first way:**

```py
df = df1[~df1.index.isin(df2.index)]
```

**second way:**

left merge 2 dataframes and then filter rows that just in df1

**third way:**

Add a column to both dataframes that define the source and then concat two dataframes with axis=1

then countt each index in data frame and filter all index that seen 1 time and has a record with source=df1

**finally:**
Use from first way. It is very very faster

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate  two tables and delete any rows that have duplicates:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

The keep parameter ask you if you want to keep the row that has duplicates or not. If keep = True, it will keep 1 copy of the rows. If false, delete all rows that have duplicates.